# Hide number elements with jquery and then Show that

Tags: jquery, html

I want hide all element that has selected with this selector `$('[href^=#Low]')` and then show one of them only.I use this code but don't worked.

How to fix this?

Html:

```
  <a href="#Low1"><h4 class="search-results-title">قوانین کنسلی بلیط قطار وحقوق مسافر </h4></a>
<a href="#Low2"><h4 class="search-results-title">جدول میزان خسارت تاخیر به مسافران قطار </h4></a>
<a href="#Low3"><h4 class="search-results-title"> شرایط و قوانین کرایه خودرو</h4></a>

<div id="low1">11111111111</div>
<div id="low2">22222222222222</div>
<div id="low3">33333333333</div>






 $('[href^=#Low]').click(function() {
            var hrefAttr = $(this).attr('href').toString().substr(1);
            $('[id^=low]').addClass('hidden');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#' + hrefAttr + '').removeClass('hidden');
                }, 2000);
            });
```

Comment: Be consistent with your capitalization.  The `href` values of the links are using a capital `L`, while the div elements are using a lowercase `l`.

Comment: I change this but don't work

Comment: `and then show one of them only.`..Means What??

Comment: I want display one of elements only

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your begins-with selector with double quotes?  `$('[href^="#Low"]')`

Comment: Here's a CodePen to demonstrate:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdQERZ

Comment: @ SimianAngel : Thank you. It solved

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.slice()` to retrieve the number at last character position of `#Low` elements which correspond to hidden `#low` element

```js
var low = $("[id^=low]").addClass("hidden"); // hide `#low` elements
$("[href^=#Low]").click(function() {
  var hrefAttr = this.href.slice(-1); // store number at end of `href`
  low.addClass("hidden"); // hide displayed `#low` element
  setTimeout(function() {
    // show `#low` element where number at end of `href` is `hrefAttr`
    $("[id=low" + hrefAttr + "]").removeClass("hidden"); 
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#Low1"><h4 class="search-results-title">قوانین کنسلی بلیط قطار وحقوق مسافر </h4></a>
<a href="#Low2"><h4 class="search-results-title">جدول میزان خسارت تاخیر به مسافران قطار </h4></a>
<a href="#Low3"><h4 class="search-results-title"> شرایط و قوانین کرایه خودرو</h4></a>

<div id="low1">11111111111</div>
<div id="low2">22222222222222</div>
<div id="low3">33333333333</div>
```